# Unable to retrieve data from Parse through getFirstInBackGround

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to retrieve data from a class in Parse called Location, where there are two columns `latitude` and `longitude`. There's another column called `Username` where the `objectId` of the user is stored.
I'm matching this `Username` with one that I have in my program, but it seems that the 'done' method used in `getFirstInBackground` isn't executing.

Here's the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < recipient_id.size(); i++) {

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Location");
                query.whereEqualTo("Username", recipient_id.get(i).toString());
                query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                        if(object==null) {

                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), locations.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else{
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            //e.printStackTrace();
                            lat = (double) object.get("latitude");
                            longi = (double) object.get("longitude");
                            Log.e("Latitude", lat+"");
                            locations.add(lat);
                            locations.add(longi);
                            Log.e("Locations", locations+"");
                        }
                    }
                });
}
Log.e("Locations", locations+"");
```

When I check my logcat, locations is shown empty. The `ArrayList` of strings `recipient_id` has `objectId`s of the users in a random order.

[image: Parse class - Location]

I have tried entering `latitude` and `longitude` data into the User class instead but the problem is still the same.

EDIT: I used `getInBackground` for querying `ParseUser` not `getFirstInBackground`.

Answer (score 0):

try to this way like.
first u can store user in parse Query array list like...

```
// Other Wise Try on this way
    for (int i = 0; i < recipient_id.size(); i++) {

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Location");
        query.whereEqualTo("Username", recipient_id.get(i).toString());
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (e == null) {
                    // Success
                    lat = (double) object.get("latitude");
                    longi = (double) object.get("longitude");
                    Log.e("Latitude", lat + "");
                    locations.add(lat);
                    locations.add(longi);
                    Log.e("Locations", locations + "");
                } else {
                    // Fail
                    // in case its fail that a time check error like
                    Log.e("get Error", " Message " + e.getMessage());
                }

            }
        });
```

try unother way like ...

```
List<ParseQuery<ParseObject>> addQuery = new ArrayList<ParseQuery<ParseObject>>();
    // first store in parse query array
    for (int i = 0; i < recipient_id.length; i++) {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Location");
        query.whereEqualTo("Username", recipient_id.get(i).toString());
        addQuery.add(query);
    }

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> fetch = ParseQuery.or(addQuery);
    fetch.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (e == null) {
                // Success
            } else {
                // Fail
                // in case its fail that a time check error like
                Log.e("get Error", " Message " + e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! In the first version of the code, what would 'object' be?

Comment: @AshishPatil 'object' have single value of data.
and in done method list is bunch of parse data.

Comment: object isn't actually defined. Tried using list[i] instead, but didn't help. Still got a null object.